# How to filter extrinsics senders?

Tags: runtime, account, origin

Let's imagine that we have some blacklist pallet that stores accounts that are restricted to make some calls. How do we implement origins filtering based on that blacklist for other pallets?

We could add corresponding logic to our own pallets, but it is not suitable for external pallets we use. We also could implement this (I guess) through adding `SignedExtension` but it is also an inappropriate solution.

It would be nice to implement this as runtime-level logic similar to how we can filter calls with `system` pallet's `BaseCallFilter` and it would be great to be able to return custom error. What are the options? Maybe we could customize `RuntimeOrigin` or smt?

Comment: does the blacklist change or it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `pallet-assets`'s `CreateOrigin`. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e85188b800c63ca3be545c1a43a0927fe0b6fd11/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L271-L277

Here's an example, we configured a whitelist(`[ROOT]`) for it. https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/ae96c262f7998174081ec57e9d45b600aaa24cec/runtime/darwinia/src/pallets/assets.rs#L41-L43

You might not need to use `EnsureOriginWithArg`, you should also take a look at `EnsureOrigin`.

Comment: Yes, wrapping `RuntimeOrigin` is a nice substrate-style solution for adjusting origin handling logic, thank you! But only in scope of specific pallet. Are there any ideas of implementing this as runtime-level logic? Like if we want to build a runtime with some role-based access to calls or something like that. Is that feasible without delving into dark deepes of substrate?